# Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly.... by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable

Tags: c#, api

I am developing a net 5 api and am trying to implement Iqueryable while querying the db. I understand the fundamental difference between IQueryable and IEnumerable. Everything works ok until I try to implement search functionality, then I get the aforementioned message in Postman: Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync. Here is my code, any help is appreciated, feel free to point me to every mistake in my code:

**Services**:

```
 public async Task<IEnumerable<TransactionsForUserVM>> 
 ShowTransactionsForSpecificUser2(QueryParameters queryParameters,
     string email)
    {
        IQueryable<TransactionsForUserVM> transactions =
                          (from t in _context.StockTransactions
                           join u in _context.Users.Where(u => u.Email == email)                          
                           on t.Email equals u.Email 
                           join s in _context.Stocks
                           on t.StockId equals s.Id
                           select new TransactionsForUserVM 
                           {
                                Id = t.Id,
                                StockId = s.Id,
                                Stock = s.Symbol,
                                Quantity = t.Quantity,
                                Purchase = t.Purchase,
                                Price = t.Price,
                                Resolved = t.Resolved,
                                Date = t.Date,
                                Email = email
                                
                         }).AsQueryable().OrderBy(s => s.Date);         

        if (queryParameters.HasQuery())
        {
                transactions = transactions
                .Where(t => t.Stock.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(queryParameters.Query.ToLowerInvariant()));
        }                                    
           return await transactions.ToListAsync();    
    }
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<TransactionsForUserVM>>> 
GetTransactionsForSpecificUser5(
    [FromQuery]QueryParameters queryParameters)
{
     var email = HttpContext.User.RetrieveEmailFromPrincipal();
     var list = await _transactionService.ShowTransactionsForSpecificUser2(queryParameters, 
     email);
    return Ok(list);
}
```

Comment: The error message you're citing is an Entity Framework error message.  It occurs when you try to use a function that's not supported by Entity Framework Linq (a different flavor of Linq than ordinary Linq).

Comment: It's probably the ToLowerInvariant that cannot be translated. But usually the database uses a case insensitive match anyway, so just remove it

Comment: Thanks man, it was that, and I spent so much time on this, especially because everything worked with ienumerable!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this

```
.Where(t => t.Stock.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(queryParameters.Query.ToLowerInvariant()));
```

To this:

```
.Where(t => t.Stock.Contains(queryParameters.Query));
```

EF Core doesn't know how to translate ToLowerInvariant into an SQL command, so it's throwing an error so you can choose to remove the operation or perform a client side evaluation (drag all the rows out the DB and then get c# to do the filter). Any time you see the "could not be translated" error it's a "you used some C# thing that has no supported mapping in SQL" indicator that you need to redesign some aspect of the C# (make it less complex)

You can find a list of supported operations (what the C# is and what  efcore can translate it to) [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sql-server/functions) . If you're not using SQLS, there  are links to other DBs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/database-functions) . You might need to approach third party documentation sites if e.g. you're using something like postgres

Comment: thanks, already excluded ToLowerInvariant and it is working fine, as Hans pointed out...I would gladly accept you as the right answer but that would not be fair to Hans...but thanks again for your effort!

Comment: Then Hans shouldn't answer questions in comments (the placeholder text for the comment box even says not to); he's been here long enough to know the rules and we're both mature enough and reputed enough to be long past caring about accumulating Fake Internet Points. I posted an answer (with additional info for you) chiefly so you could have something to mark as answered so the question shows green on the dashboard, which means other people know it no longer requires an answer. Typically, questions that are answered in comments don't receive an answer; something of a housekeeping headache too

Comment: (If Hans does post an answer, feel free to swap it ;)  - also you're allowed to post and accept your own answers after getting pointers in comments, which additionally helps future visitors landing on the same question)